# Chrome extension : jQuery.js conflicts in background file conflics with plugins in websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am including jQuery in background_page like this,

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery.js"></script>
```

Here's the problem:

In websites, where jQuery plugins are used (with jQuery.extend method), they do not work when my extension is installed.

I guess this is because I had my jQuery.js over 'their' jQuery.js' file and all .extend do not work.

So, I thought of adding jQuery.js only when its not avaialable. So, I tried adding jQuery like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src = "libs/jquery.js";
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    </script>
```

But no luck.

Can someone suggest me a good way to add jQuery.js file in background page.

Comment: @jfriend00 http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html

Background pages run in background of every page.

Comment: Are you injecting jQuery into the pages? Otherwise background_page scripts should never conflict with tab scripts.

Comment: What do you mean by injecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer later,

Doing
[jQuery.nocConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

jQ = jQuery.noConflict
and replacing `$` with `jQ` everywhere, solved the problem.

**Conclusion:**  `content_scripts` can **also** interfere with webpage javascripts.

Answer (score 1):

I really like your approach here, but I would recommend enwrapping your declaration inside of a `load` event listener:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) { // for IE8 and below
  window.attachEvent('onload', init);
}

function init() {
  if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "libs/jquery.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
}
```

I think the issue may be that at the time you're asking if `jQuery` is an object, that the DOM hasn't loaded yet.

**Alternatively**, you can load jQuery via your Manifest File under `content_scripts`: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html

Comment: So, when does the background page loads. I thought it loads after the page you are browsing loads completely.

Comment: Do you have a Manifest File? http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/manifest.html

Comment: Yes,
All basic files are included like this,


 
 {
            "css":[ "css/global.css" ],
            "js":[ "libs/basic.js", "libs/jquery.js", "libs/jquery.mousetracing.js", "libs/jquery.longclick.js", "libs/ModalPopups.js", "blacklist.js", "js/quic_link_api.js", "js/facebook.js", "js/custom.js", "quick_link.js" ],
            "matches":[ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
            "run_at":"document_start"
        },

Comment: I updated my answer. The `content_scripts` parameter may be your answer.

Comment: I have looked into content_scripts too. 

Will it work on background pages too ? I dont think so.

Comment: It is my understanding that background pages are just a function of your Chrome extension. You should be able to use the `content_scripts` parameter within your manifest object in order to call jQuery for your extension. `background_page` is a parameter of said object and I don't see that declared in yours.